# Jquery drag and drop into empty div and back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was having difficulty trying to figure out how to drag and drop between two different div's and I found a reference to `http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#option-connectWith` in another post and it works magnificently... Almost anyway.

I am now able to drag items between divs but if I drag the last item from a div it becomes closed to me. I can't drag anything back into it... Is there something basic I am missing?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How about setting a `min-height` on the div?

Comment: Thanks, I feel extremely stupid right now.

Comment: We've all been there! :D

Comment: I definitely need to do more front end work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a `display:none;` element in each `div`

Comment: Yeah, I figured this out after that comment. Thanks! I feel stupid for missing something so obvious.

Answer (score 1):

When you drag the last element from the div it's likely collapsing, which is almost like removing the div. As state in the comment you should set a min-height for the div, and possibly a min-width as well to prevent the div for collapsing when it's empty.